# Overcoming network filtering issues when using UDP broadcast/multicast for simple service discovery

Tags: c#, udp, ip, multicast

I am working on a service discovery implementation in C#. In an attempt to get around some issues, I have implemented both broadcast and multicast, simplified to the snippets shown.

**Client side broadcast:**

```
var requestData = new byte[]{ /* Whatever */}

// Configure broadcast
var ipBroadcastEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 12301);
var broadcastServerEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

var broadcastClient = new UdpClient {EnableBroadcast = true};
broadcastClient.Client.Bind(_broadcastServerEp);

// Send a request:
broadcastClient.Send(requestData, requestData.Length, ipBroadcastEndPoint);

// Listen for a reply:
var broadcastserverEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
var broadcastserverResponseData = broadcastClient.Receive(ref broadcastserverEp);
```

**Client side multicast:**

```
var requestData = new byte[]{ /* Whatever */}

// Configure multicast
var ipMulticastEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.253"), 12302);
var multicastServerEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

var multicastClient = new UdpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
multicastClient.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.253"), 32);
multicastClient.Client.Bind(_multicastServerEp);

// Send a request:
multicastClient.Send(requestData, requestData.Length, ipMulticastEndPoint);

// Listen for a reply:
var multicastserverEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
var multicastserverResponseData = multicastClient.Receive(ref multicastserverEp);
```

**Server side broadcast:**

```
// Listen for broadcast
Task.Run(() =>
{
    var broadcastServer = new UdpClient(12301);
    while(/**/)
    {
        var broadcastclientEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        var broadcastclientRequestData = broadcastServer.Receive(ref broadcastclientEp);

        // Reply to broadcast:
        var responseData = new byte[]{ /* Whatever */}
        broadcastServer.Send(responseData, responseData.Length, broadcastclientEp);
    }
}
```

**Server side multicast:**

```
// Listen for multicast
Task.Run(() =>
{
    var multicastServer = new UdpClient(12302);
    multicastServer.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse("239.255.255.253"));
    while(/**/)
    {
        var multicastclientEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        var multicastclientRequestData = multicastServer.Receive(ref multicastclientEp);

        // Reply to multicast:
        var responseData = new byte[]{ /* Whatever */}
        multicastServer.Send(responseData, responseData.Length, multicastclientEp);
    }
}
```

If both client and server components are running on the same computer, both broadcast and multicast work as expected.

If both client and server components are on different computers in the same subnet, broadcast works, multicast works in one direction only (two computers in a given WLAN topology, multicast works when one of them is in the server role, but not the other way around).

If both client and server components are on different subnets in the same corporate network, neither broadcast or multicast works.

I'd like to get this to work reliably across subnets. From what I've learned so far, I know broadcast won't work, but multicast should.

Is there some magic to the selection of multicast addresses and/or port numbers? In other words, are there specific addresses and ports I should or should not be using for it to work reliably regardless of network topology? Are there address/port combinations which are customarily filtered or customarily kept open? Are there any configuration options I have overlooked?

Comment: Multicast is not meant to be used across subnets.  The issue is there is a lot of multicast and broadcast messages in a subnet.  When you allow multicast to go across subnets you end up flooding a subnet with these messages.  The subnet is defined by the mask.  So carefully designing your network masks may solve issue.  You may want to use a bridge where you use a TCP or UDP to connect subnets and forward specific multicast messages between subnets.  Some routers have settings to limit which multicast messages are allowed to go between subnets.

Comment: Read this Cisco webpage : https://www.cisco.com/assets/sol/sb/Switches_Emulators_v2_3_5_xx/help/250/index.html#page/tesla_250_olh/multi_forwarding.html

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the info. It does leave me wondering how service discovery can work for things like software product license servers or printers where a LAN is split into multiple subnets. Do they only work within subnets, do they require explicit router configuration, or do they use some other technique than SLP-style broadcast/multicast?

Comment: You are creating a Multicast Bridge which you ca search the web.  The general term for the bridge is Port Forwarding which is a general tern for moving messages from one subnet to another subnet.  The type of Port Forwarding depends on the physical and the amount of traffic you need to forward (or not forward so you don't flood the network).  If you were trying to forward from NY to california you would use a Cisco Router like in the link.  In same room you may just change settings on a router to pass data.  Port Forwarding can be accomplished with either software or hardware.

Comment: Only broadcast messages are blocked by routers.  Normally IP addresses (or computer names) are hard coded and not discovered.  Outside a subnet either IP Routing using IP address and masks are used or ARP Protocol is used to find devices outside the subnet or DHCP where a server has list of computers.  A subnet has a gateway which is used as a default route to find devices outside a subnet.  A network is like a tree structure where the subnet is a leaf and the gateway leads to the root which is the global internet.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing multicast traffic to pass between subnets is controlled entirely by the routers between those subnets.

The routers need to be configured to either with static multicast routes, or to accept IGMP messages from hosts to set up multicast groups as they are joined.

Comment: Routers block multicast unless you specifially setup the routers to allow multicast IP to pass.  Most routers have setting to allow the multicast to pass.